# Why do Bayesian methods achieve sparsity via normal likelihood and Gamma hyperprior?

Tags: bayesian, sparse

In the view of $\ell_1$ regularization, a natural way to incorporate sparsity into a Bayesian model is to add a [Laplacian prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) in my opinion. But instead of this, a usual fashion to handle sparsity in Bayesian model is the method proposed in the paper [Sparse Bayesian Learning and the Relevance Vector Machine](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume1/tipping01a/tipping01a.pdf). What is the difference between these two in practice? Are there comparative studies of them? Thank you.

Comment: Adding a Laplacian prior will not necessarily create a sparse model, unless you use the MAP point estimate (which is not always the right choice).

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon Can you give more comments/references/examples on the mechanism about why MAP point estimate is sometimes appropriate/sparse Bayesian model is more general than $\ell_1$ regularization?

Comment: *Sparsity and the Bayesian Perspective* is a good paper that explains well.